# Google classroom API Insufficient authentication scopes

Tags: python, google-authentication, google-classroom

I try to add courseWork from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-coursework) but It shows an `Request has insufficient authentication scopes` error.

> scopes are [here](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/auth)

I tried this:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
creds = store.get()

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students'

if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('classroom', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

courseWork = {  
  'title': 'Ant colonies',  
  'description': 'Read the article about ant colonies and complete the quiz.',  
  'materials': [  
     {'link': { 'url': 'http://example.com/ant-colonies' }},  
     {'link': { 'url': 'http://example.com/ant-quiz' }}  
],  
  'workType': 'ASSIGNMENT',  
  'state': 'PUBLISHED',  
}  
courseWork = service.courses().courseWork().create(courseId='105332016379', body=courseWork).execute()  
print('Assignment created with ID {0}'.format(courseWork.get('id')))
```

And error shows like this:

[image: Error]

So what will be the solution?

Comment: Using Google Scripts to do the same thing, I had to set up: "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly"] Have you just set up coursework but also need to set up courses?

Comment: @TomKeeler yes ,
I just set up coursework and also want to setup courses.